# error while connecting to ssh on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud, ubuntu-18.04, plesk

I have my instance running on Google Cloud Platform but suddenly my websites stops working and when i try to login via ssh, it keep connecting not never connects. It says:

The key transfer to project metadata is taking an unusually long time. Transferring instead to instance metadata may be faster, but will transfer the keys only to this VM. If you wish to SSH into other VMs from this VM, you will need to transfer the keys accordingly.
Click here to transfer the key to instance metadata. Note that this setting is persistent and needs to be disabled in the Instance Details page once enabled.
You can drastically improve your key transfer times by migrating to OS Login.

when i check metadata, it shows unusual activity, which says

google-ssh {"userName":"XXXXXXX@XXXX.com","expireOn":"2021-09-24T10:12:18+0000"}

While checking error log:

{
"insertId": "1",
"jsonPayload": {
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent",
"earlyBootReportEvent": {
"policyEvaluationPassed": false,
"actualMeasurements": [
{
"value": "UcMj3gwMaU9GAc3QK+tY/xNin3Q=",
"hashAlgo": "SHA1",
"pcrNum": "PCR_0"
},
{
"hashAlgo": "SHA1",
"value": "YGw/kvTUppYy0LdmFR51+E97gnU=",
"pcrNum": "PCR_4"
},
{
"pcrNum": "PCR_5",
"value": "4oHSmdohc7EolEkGBRqNkJu/s3k=",
"hashAlgo": "SHA1"
},
{
"pcrNum": "PCR_7",
"hashAlgo": "SHA1",
"value": "47JeCjb+lbFLd9hY8wGzli65zS4="
}
],
"policyMeasurements": [
{
"pcrNum": "PCR_0",
"hashAlgo": "SHA1",
"value": "UcMj3gwMaU9GAc3QK+tY/xNin3Q="
},
{
"pcrNum": "PCR_4",
"hashAlgo": "SHA1",
"value": "SNvS2TFD0ijbVgPoQkMPdwAyg/w="
},
{
"value": "47JeCjb+lbFLd9hY8wGzli65zS4=",
"pcrNum": "PCR_7",
"hashAlgo": "SHA1"
}
]
},
"bootCounter": "11"
},
"resource": {
"type": "gce_instance",
"labels": {
"zone": "us-central1-X",
"project_id": "myhost-XXXXXX",
"instance_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
},
"timestamp": "2021-09-24T06:13:26.266965195Z",
"severity": "ERROR",
"logName": "projects/myhost-XXXXXX/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fshielded_vm_integrity",
"receiveTimestamp": "2021-09-24T06:13:28.275282350Z"
}

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Extensive details about the Integrity Event Failure are posted as comments to your other question. Do not cross-post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316656/error-while-connecting-to-ssh-on-google-cloud-platform

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused due to a firewall rule blocking SSH traffic or HTTP/HTTPS traffic.
You may need to double-check the Firewall rules, and if the Firewalls are not the issue then, you could try to look in this [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh), as the issue could be for a couple of reasons.

And in the worst case, you could just recreate the instance.